# Deleting the parent in a one-to-many relationship throws MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, one-to-many

I have a classic one-to-many situation. One cart, has many items.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CART")
public class Cart {

//...

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="cart")
@Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE })
private Set<Items> items;

// getters and setters
}
```

The special thing to notice is the ***CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE***,

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ITEMS")
public class Items {

//...
@ManyToOne
private Cart cart;

public Items() {}

// getters and setters
}
```

The behavior I'm trying to accomplish:

- The cart gets update or saved, the items should get updated or saved.
- The cart gets deleted, the items should **NOT** get deleted. (The items have their own life-cycle.)
- The cart gets deleted, the foreign key on the items table should be set to null.

With the current implementation, the last point is not happening. Running the code and deleting a cart leads to:

```
 MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails ...
```

What is the recommended hibernate solution for situations like these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set cart attribute of items as `null` before removing the cart:

```
Cart cartToDel = cartRepository.getOne(1l);
cartToDel.getItems().forEach(item -> item.setCart(null));
cartRepository.delete(cartToDel);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
items.setCart(null);
session.update(items);
session.delete(cart);
transaction1.commit();
```